# Output does not print result even though the two choices are none but the first option is the right choice in python list

Tags: python, list, nested

Good evening.

I want to ask why is it that there are no results for my code below even though 3 is the price for the celfone and I inputted none for the upper price and none for the search brand. The output is "You did not enter any search parameters."

A snippet of my code is below:

```
def search_celfone():
templist = []
temp = []
count = 0

lower_price = input("Enter lower bound of price: ")
upper_price = input("Enter upper bound of price: ")
search_brand = str(input("Enter brand name: ")).upper()

#IF CHOICES 1 AND 2 ARE NONE
if lower_price == "none" and upper_price == "none": 
    for cp in celfones:
        temp = celfones[count]
        count += 1

    #IF CHOICES 1 AND 2 ARE NONE AND CHOICE 3 IS IN THE LIST
        if temp[1] == search_brand:
            templist.append(temp)
            break

    #IF CHOICES 1 AND 2 ARE NONE AND CHOICE 3 IS NOT IN THE LIST INCLUDING NONE
        else:
            temp[1] != search_brand
            continue
        break   

#IF CHOICE 1 IS INTEGER AND CHOICES 2 AND 3 ARE NONE    
elif lower_price != "none" and upper_price == "none" and search_brand == "none":
    lower_price = float(lower_price)
    for cp in celfones:
        temp = celfones[count]
        count += 1


        if temp[1] == search_brand and temp[2] >= lower_price:
            templist.append(temp)
            break
        #elif temp[1] == search_brand and temp[2] >= lower_price:
            #templist.append(temp)
            #break
        #elif 

        #elif temp[1] != search_brand or temp[2] >= lower_price:
        elif temp[1] != search_brand and temp[2] >= lower_price:
            continue
        break               


else:
    print ("you did not enter any search parameter") 
count += 1
print (templist)
buyer_menu()
```

> BUYER MODE

==============================
[1] Display all celfones
[2] Search celfone according
    to price and brand

## [3] Go back to previous menu

CHOICE >>> 2
Enter lower bound of price: 3
Enter upper bound of price: none
Enter brand name: none
you did not enter any search parameter

## []

> CHOICE >>> 1
>   There are 2  celfones in the list.
>   1. Lumia, NOKIA, Php3.0
>   Features:
>   2. Xperia, SONY, Php4.0
>   Features:

==============================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look deeper at these lines of code:

```
    if temp[1] == search_brand and temp[2] >= lower_price:
        templist.append(temp)
        break
    elif temp[1] != search_brand and temp[2] >= lower_price:
        continue
    break
```

`search_brand` is, by virtue of the snippet `and search_brand == "none":` none.  Thus, you won't find any matches until you add a "none" brand phone.  In addition, the first time it runs through the loop where `temp[2] < lower_price`, it'll break out of the loop, ignoring any later matching object.

I'd recommend removing both `break` statements within that snippet, and ignoring the search_brand entirely in the `if` statements.

Comment: Also note that the input `search_brand` string is converted to upper case, so if "none" is inputted it will actually be "NONE".

Comment: @PM2Ring True, nice catch.  In that case, jeb, you should also change `and search_brand == "none":` to `and search_brand == "NONE":`.  Otherwise, you won't ever get a match for that if statement.

Comment: tried removing the "break" from the snippet but it does not print the nokia brand which has a price of 3. I'm trying to test an input for an amount like 3 which is the price of nokia and then type none in the upper price and type also none in the search brand. Like, 3 and none and none but it will still have an output of nokia because 3 is the price of nokia. thanks!

Comment: @jeb Have you changed `and search_brand == "none":` to and `search_brand == "NONE":`?  If you don't, then because of the line `search_brand = str(input("Enter brand name: ")).upper()` and particularly `.upper()` you'll never enter that portion of code.

Comment: @Fawful yes.  #IF CHOICE 1 IS INTEGER AND CHOICES 2 AND 3 ARE NONE 
 elif lower_price != "none" and upper_price == "none" and search_brand == "NONE":
  lower_price = float(lower_price)
  for cp in celfones:
   temp = celfones[count]
   count += 1
  
   if temp[1] == search_brand and temp[2] >= lower_price:
   templist.append(temp)
   
   elif temp[1] != search_brand and temp[2] >= lower_price:
    continue

Comment: @jeb Try removing `temp[1] == search_brand and` from the `if` statement.

Comment: @Fawful, I already removed but still no output of celfones. I even tried inputting 3 for both nokia and sony celfone brands but still no output. it should have an output of nokia and sony listings because 3 is equal to the price of celfones in my list.      here is my editted code:  elif lower_price != "none" and upper_price == "none" and search_brand == "NONE":
  lower_price = float(lower_price)
  for cp in celfones:
   temp = celfones[count]
   count += 1
  
   if temp[2] >= lower_price:
   templist.append(temp)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. I have already found a solution to this problem. I just did a major modification for the function.

The major differences are:

- I immediately placed the for loop after the three choices.
- I removed several for loops inside.
- I also had a hard time figuring and applying the truth table for the if and elif statements. (I'm just a newbie in programming)
- Plus, I also removed the break from all statements. Thanks for this input  @Fawful
- Also, I changed the "none" into "NONE" for some statements. Thanks for this input @PM 2Ring

For those interested, below is my modified code:

```
for cp in celfones:
    temp = celfones[count]
    tempf = temp[3]
    count += 1

    if lower_price == "none" and upper_price == "none": 

        if temp[1] == search_brand:
            templist.append(temp)

    elif lower_price != "none" and upper_price == "none":
        lower_price = float(lower_price)

        if temp[1] == search_brand and temp[2] >= lower_price:
            templist.append(temp)

        elif search_brand == "NONE" and temp[2] >= lower_price:
            templist.append(temp)

    elif lower_price == "none" and upper_price != "none":
        upper_price = float(upper_price)

        if temp[1] == search_brand and temp[2] <= upper_price:
            templist.append(temp)

        elif search_brand == "NONE" and temp[2] <= upper_price:
            templist.append(temp)

    elif lower_price != "none" and upper_price != "none":
        lower_price = float(lower_price)
        upper_price = float(upper_price)

        if search_brand == "NONE" and temp[2] >= lower_price and temp[2] <= upper_price:
            templist.append(temp)

        elif temp[1] == search_brand and temp[2] >= lower_price and temp[2] <= upper_price:
            templist.append(temp)

    else:
        print ("you did not enter any search parameter") 


print (len(templist), "celfone(s) found.")  ### counting of results
```